# How to insert 20 million items in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, insert, illegalargumentexception

Data :

```
{
  "Keys": "word1",
  "word2",
  "word3",
  ....."word19999999",
  "word20000000"
}
```

I trying to insert data in **MongoDB** and it error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
```

My code:

```
// keys 20m arrays
 DBObject keyDB = new BasicDBObject("keys", keys);
 mdbc.insertOne(keyDB);`
```

How to insert 20 million items in **MongoDB** without error?

Comment: Documents in Mongo are limited to 16MB in size. Thus, you can't.

Comment: Right, you likely want to create 20 million documents, instead of one document with 20 million array elements.